# Cobalt atomic mass less than 100 % isotope mass?

Tags: nuclear-physics, mass, elements, isotopes

Why is cobalt's atomic mass listed on periodic tables as less than 59 amu when its main isotope (virtually 100 %) is cobalt 59 with a trace of cobalt 60? After reading a bit I'm wondering if it has to do with loss of mass through decay. But that seems like it would either change the mass number or only lose an insignificant mass of electrons.

Comment: Protons and neutrons bound in nuclei weigh a bit less due to binding energy.

Comment: The mass of Co-59 is 58.933 amu because of that binding energy.

Answer (score 19):

The mass of an atom is actually a little bit smaller than the sum of the
masses of its constituents ([protons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton), [neutrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron), [electrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron)).
The missing difference is due to the negative binding energy of the nucleus, which
according to Einstein's $E=mc^2$ results in the so-called [mass defect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy#Mass_defect).
The [nuclear binding energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy#Nuclear_binding_energy_curve) is typically berween $-7.5$ and
$-8.8$ MeV per nucleon, thus resulting in a mass defect
between $-0.0080$ and $-0.0094$ amu per nucleon.

For the cobalt-59 atom we have the following mass contributions:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
27 \text{ protons}   & 27\cdot 1.0073\text{ amu} & 27.197\text{ amu} \\ \hline
32 \text{ neutrons}  & 32\cdot 1.0087\text{ amu} & 32.278\text{ amu} \\ \hline
27 \text{ electrons} & 27\cdot 0.0005\text{ amu} & \ 0.015\text{ amu} \\ \hline
\text{nuclear binding energy} & & \color{red}{-0.557\text{ amu}}  \\ \hline
\text{total} & & 58.933\text{ amu}  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: And this has to be in order for nuclear fusion to be exothermic.

Comment: .... and the AMU is slightly more than one proton mass due to the historical definition from carbon, meaning it includes carbon's mass defect? Somehow I never put this together until I saw your chart... :-(

Comment: @GlennWillen You probably mean "the AMU is slightly *less* than one proton mass". But yes, the AMU definition from carbon includes carbon's mass defect.

Comment: Oops, thank you, math is hard.